# jQuery Validate Plugin - Error messages not removed immediately after field becomes valid

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery Validate plugin on a form like below:

JS:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function ValidateFields() {

    $("#createProgramForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: { required: true, minlength: 2 },
            lastname: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: { minlength: "Minimum 2 characters." },
            lastname: { required: "Please enter a last name." }
        }
    });


    if ($("#createProgramForm").valid()) {
        alert("Form is valid");
    }

}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <form id="createProgramForm">
        <p>
            <label for="firstname">
                First Name</label>
            <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastname">First Name</label>
            <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <button onclick="ValidateFields();">Validate</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

When I click Validate, the validation error messages are shown next to the fields. But the error messages don't go away once the field becomes valid like in the demo [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/). Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Setting the success property like so - success: function(){} solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Um, works for me.  Perhaps try the latest jquery.validate plugin?  The version I used was [here](http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js)

Comment: I do have the latest validate plugin. But still doesn't work like the demo. I'm using IE 9.